# Computing the angle between two vectors using the inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Question is: Consider $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the inner product $\langle u1,u2\rangle=x_1x_2+3y_1y_2+z_1z_2$ where $u_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $u_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ are two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. What is the cosine of the angle between the vectors $v=(2,1,3)$ and $w=(-1,2,-1)$ with respect to the above inner product?

I don't even understand what exactly the inner product is,I tried using the formula
 $\cos(\theta)=\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{|v||w|}$ but I don't understand how to use the inner product in this case. Any help would be much appreciated. I don't understand what to even substitute in the formula.

Comment: Please make titles informative!!!!!!

Comment: Does the angle change just because you are using another inner product?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\cos\theta=\dfrac{\langle u_1,u_2\rangle}{|u_1||u_2|}\\
\implies \cos\theta=\dfrac{-2+6-3}{\sqrt{4+3+9}\sqrt{1+12+1}}$$
For the meaning of the inner product, see the images and the information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: The question is not using the standard inner product.

Comment: answer is 1/4sqrt(14)

Comment: @SantiagoCanez I edited my answer.

Comment: Still incorrect. The lengths depend on the inner product.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez so what exactly do we do?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez I edited my answer again. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I’m answering this question exactly 10 years later, i.e 31 March 2024, so I’m not sure how relevant it might be but to anyone who needs it in the future,

**Hint:**  The numerator can be expressed as

$\langle u1,u2 \rangle = x_1x_2 + 3y_1y_2 +z_1z_2$

which is fairly easy to compute.

For the denominator, recollect that the distance function is defined as

$\sqrt{\langle u1,u1 \rangle} = \sqrt{x_1^2 + 3y_1^2 + z_1^2 }$

And

$||u1|| = \sqrt{\langle u1,u1 \rangle}$.

Use similar steps to calculate the value of length for the vector $u2$ , based on the newly defined inner product, and then you can plug them into the formula for the angle to obtain the result